# Complex SQL SUM query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I'm doing a complex query that returns the number of accounts and clients each of our employees have.  It currently looks like this:

```
select e.employee_id, p.first_name, p.last_name, clients.client_count, 
accounts.account_count, properties.property_count
from app.Employee e 
inner join app.Person p on e.person_id = p.person_id
inner join
(
select exc.employee_id, count(*) as client_count from app.client c
inner join 
(
    select employee_id, ecs.client_id from app.EmployeeClient ec
    inner join  
        (select client_id, max(effective_dt_tm) as effective from app.EmployeeClient ec where ec.employee_client_role_cd = 6001 group by client_id) ecs
        on ecs.client_id = ec.client_id and ecs.effective = ec.effective_dt_tm
        where ec.employee_client_role_cd = 6001 
    )exc on exc.client_id = c.client_id
    WHERE c.account_status_cd <> 4057
    group by exc.employee_id 
    )as clients on e.employee_id = clients.employee_id
inner join
(
    select exc.employee_id, count(*) as account_count from app.client c
    inner join app.account a on c.client_id = a.client_id
    inner join 
    (
        select employee_id, ecs.client_id from app.EmployeeClient ec
        inner join  
        (select client_id, max(effective_dt_tm) as effective from app.EmployeeClient ec where ec.employee_client_role_cd = 6001 group by client_id) ecs
        on ecs.client_id = ec.client_id and ecs.effective = ec.effective_dt_tm
        where ec.employee_client_role_cd = 6001 
    )exc on exc.client_id = c.client_id
    where a.active_ind = 1 AND a.account_status_reason_cd IS NULL
    group by exc.employee_id
)as accounts on e.employee_id = accounts.employee_id
inner join
(
    select exc.employee_id, count(*) as property_count from app.client c
    inner join app.account a on c.client_id = a.client_id
    inner join app.AccountProperty ap on a.account_id = ap.account_id
    inner join 
    (
        select employee_id, ecs.client_id from app.EmployeeClient ec
        inner join  
        (select client_id, max(effective_dt_tm) as effective from app.EmployeeClient ec where ec.employee_client_role_cd = 6001 group by client_id) ecs
        on ecs.client_id = ec.client_id and ecs.effective = ec.effective_dt_tm
        where ec.employee_client_role_cd = 6001 
    )exc on exc.client_id = c.client_id
    where ap.account_property_status_cd ! = 4255
    group by exc.employee_id 
)as properties on e.employee_id = properties.employee_id
ORDER BY employee_id
```

I am needing to add a column that will sum the total billing amount for all accounts per employee.  I have a function that already calculates the billing amount for each account and could use a cross apply like this to add it to the query:

```
cross apply(
    select total_billing_amt from [App].[fGetAccountBillingAmounts] (a.account_id,'2016-12-08')
    ) as billing_amounts
```

I believe this would need to go in the section where I'm counting total accounts because that is the only place I am pulling an account number so something like this:

```
inner join
(
    select exc.employee_id, count(*) as account_count, billing_amounts.total_billing_amt from app.client c
    inner join app.account a on c.client_id = a.client_id
    inner join 
    (
        select employee_id, ecs.client_id from app.EmployeeClient ec
        inner join  
        (select client_id, max(effective_dt_tm) as effective from app.EmployeeClient ec where ec.employee_client_role_cd = 6001 group by client_id) ecs
        on ecs.client_id = ec.client_id and ecs.effective = ec.effective_dt_tm
        where ec.employee_client_role_cd = 6001 
    )exc on exc.client_id = c.client_id
    cross apply(
        select total_billing_amt from [App].[fGetAccountBillingAmounts] (a.account_id,'2016-12-08')
    ) as billing_amounts
    where a.active_ind = 1 AND a.account_status_reason_cd IS NULL
    group by exc.employee_id
)as accounts on e.employee_id = accounts.employee_id
```

This will run ok, but returns multiple rows with the same employee listed multiple times for each accounts billing total.  I haven't been able to figure out how to sum this up for each employee.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm just using Microsoft's SQL Server Management Studio

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
cross apply(
    select sum(total_billing_amt) as total_billing_amt from [App].[fGetAccountBillingAmounts] (a.account_id,'2016-12-08')
) as billing_amounts
```

Your cross apply could be returning multiple rows?

Comment: No, it should only be returning one row because the function is summing all charges for one account.  But each employee has multiple accounts so it needs to run that function for each account which then needs to be summed for that employee.